# hide all tabs pickers on opening a subPage rather than just the parents tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

We have this design for our Ionic app

This is made by our main page having a tabs component displayed at the top and the schedule page having a tabs component with buttons displayed at the bottom.

[image]

When a user clicks on one of the cards (that’s in the page scheduleActivities) it does a function which does

```
this.navController.push(‘InformationPage’);
```

`tabsHideOnSubPages` boolean has been set on all places as well as on each tab element and behaves normally for most cases in the application.

However in this case, the tabs bar in the parent hides correctly (the tabs at the top), but the tabs bar in the parents parent (the one at the bottom that is rendered the home screen) does not.

Is it possible to change the behaviour to hide all tabs pickers, on opening a subPage rather than just the parents tabs.

- Initially raised on the Ionic forums here - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/possible-issue-with-tabshideonsubpages/122681?u=jamesnurse